# Subclipse description of each menu item

Tags: svn, subclipse

Is there a description of each of the menu items in the **Team** menu for *Subclipse* somewhere?

The are still a number of items that I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Check these two links, maybe you can find some useful stuff there:

- http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/org.tigris.subclipse.doc/topics/toc.html
- http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/PluginFAQ

Here are the descriptions of some of them, please specify if there's any other one you don't understand.

**Synchronize with repository** Compare changes on your version with HEAD in a visual way. It shows incoming updates and outgoing files to commit. If you double click any of these files, you get a visual diff of the changes.

**Commit** - Commit your changes

**Create / Apply patch** - Create or apply a patch. ([how to](http://ariejan.net/2007/07/03/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-subversion/))

**Revert** - Revert your changes

**Edit conflicts** - In case you have conflicts in your project.

**Branch/tag/merging** items - See [Chapter 4](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.html) on the book.

**Set property / show properties** See [Properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.html).

**Export** - Use [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) on your project (opens file browser to select where).

**Show History** - Show svn log in a "nice way".

**Mark resolved** - In case there was a conflict, mark your version as resolved.